# is there are any way to stop rendering current page using HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to stop rendering the page and exit when the user's browser doesn't have JavaScript enabled or support,
    
      
    
I want it like how exit() works in PHP. 
Is it possible via HTML?

Comment: Why don't you just check if javascript is supported, and then redirect to a page if it's not?

Comment: `<noscript> ` is one option

Comment: @DonnyP i am also interested in this. how will you redirect?

Comment: @DonnyP If JavaScript is not supported you have no way to check if JavaScript is supported. `<noscript>` is the HTML way to do this.

Comment: PHP `exit()` does not stop rendering. When exit runs, rendering hasn't even begun.

Comment: I meant like how exit() works ... stop executing the script..... like that I want to know is it possible to stop the HTML rendering via HTML @bfavaretto

Comment: this is confused, js,php,html all work diffirently. call the php via AJAX so no js = no php, but this sounds like a rather confused approach - why do you want to do this? what about search engines? does it really matter if you run a little php if the use has no js support (which will be very few)? a fuller explanation of your reasoning would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">body { display: none; } </style>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://redirectpage.com/">
</noscript>
```

Comment: Relaying on modern browsers ;)

Answer (score 3):

technically wrong but there is some browser support.

```
   <noscript>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=noscript.html">
    </noscript>
```

Comment: Does this actually stop rendering the page though (assuming the redirect target does not finish loading before rendering the current page has finished anyway)?

Comment: subjectively yes, objectively no. proving negatives has always be a problem.

Comment: what do you mean by technically wrong?

Comment: will it stop parsing other script in the page (JavaScript, PHP, which are later included in body)

Comment: no. php is server-side, its (almost-always) finished before a single byte hits the browser

Comment: I believe this proves your negative (at least in HTML5): http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-refresh

Comment: ah well html5 i haven't caught up with that. 3 is good enough for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. What you could do, however, is add a stylesheet blanking out the page inside a `<noscript>` tag:

```
<noscript>
<style>
* { display: none; }
</style>
</noscript>
```

Of course that would hide everything; not just stuff that occurs later on the page.

Another option that's very common is adding a `no-js` CSS class to the `<body>` tag which you remove as early as possible using JavaScript. That was you can properly create CSS rules to show/hide elements based on the (non-)existence of that class.

Comment: But it won't stop the other scripts in the page from parsing...

Comment: Which scripts? You don't have any working scripts if the user has disabled JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you use the noscript tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" >
        //  [whatever JS is appropriate]
        </script>
        <noscript>
              <!-- Browser doesn't support JavaScript, so go elsewhere -->
              <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://some.other-website.com/"> 
        </noscript>

    </head>
    <body>
        .... The rest of the HTML body

    </body>
</html>
```

This only works in the <head> section with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use ThiefMaster's and Dagon's concept together, as fallback support

Comment: Such a nice `comment`